# Android: setbackground layout to button

Tags: android, layout, setbackground

I want to do the following:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.caracbout);
```

But this function only works like this:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxxx);
```

my button is

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:background="@layout/boutcarac"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Refresh"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="refreshfiche"/>
```

and my layout caracbout xml is like

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="-90"
                android:startColor="#0000"
                android:endColor="#fff5d6"  />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item style="@style/typocarac">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#fff5d6" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="-90"
                android:startColor="#fff5d6"
                android:endColor="#0000"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

and I must change the item android:state_pressed="true", so I want to create a xml caracbout2 and set it in the java. But I dont know how can I do that.
Thanks!

Comment: create your caracbout2 xml file in directory drawable and use R.drawable.caracbout2 in java

Comment: OMAGAD!!! thanks!! I'm a newbie, I thought "drawable" was only for jpg or image file........................ thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. I add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your caracbout2 xml file in directory drawable and use R.drawable.caracbout2 in java

you can learn from [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for drawable resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background like this,

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Layouts are not background images. They contain the information which is necessary to draw application views/screens. To draw a button with custom background you can use drawable resource file.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: thanks but I do not have a choice in fact, here is my xml

Comment: Can't you inflate the button from your layout?